# How to Define the command \ choice and the Ex environment to compile with the desired results

Tags: macros

I have a LaTeX file with the following content

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\def\choice ....??? %Help me define the \ choice command and ex environment
\NewEnviron{ex}{...???} %Help me define the \ choice command and ex environment
\begin{document}

\choice{2}
\begin{ex}
an example
\end{ex}
\begin{ex}
A question developed from the example above
\end{ex}
\choice{3}
\begin{ex}
another example
\end{ex}
\begin{ex}
A question develops from this second example
\end{ex}
\begin{ex}
A question develops from this second example 
\end{ex}
\choice{5}
\begin{ex}
another example
\end{ex}
\begin{ex}
A question develops from this third example
\end{ex}
\begin{ex}
A question develops from this third example
\end{ex}
\begin{ex}
A question develops from this third example
\end{ex}
\begin{ex}
A question develops from this third example
\end{ex}

\end{document}
```

Define the command \ choice and ex environment to be able to compile the resulting .PDF file as follows

```
exam 1: an example
Question 1.1: A question developed from the example above
exam 2: another example
Question 2.1: A question develops from this second example
Question 2.1: A question develops from this second example
exam 3: another example
Question 3.1: A question develops from this third example
Question 3.2: A question develops from this third example
Question 3.3: A question develops from this third example
Question 3.4: A question develops from this third example
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me

Comment: What do you want to output the "compile as a result" to, a plain text file or PDF file?

Comment: yes. I want to compile it into PDF file. Thank you for responding. Hope you solve help me.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Please specify what you need `\choice` and the `ex` environment to do, and please add the `\documentclass`, `\begin{document`/`\end{document}}` lines and the necessary packages to your code.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I have revised the content of this question

Comment: It's not clear at all what `\choice` is supposed to do.

Comment: For example, the command \ choice {5} then has 5 ex environment and compiled into: exam 1; Question 1.1; Question 1.2; Question 1.3; Question 1.4

Answer (score 1):

If I got it right, then `\choice` says how many of the following `ex`-environments are to be composed to an exam(ple).
The first of these following `ex`-environments is to be used for the exam(ple)-heading.
The second and more of these following `ex`-environments are to be used as questions that are numbered within the number of the exam(ple)-heading.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\newtheorem{exthm}{exam}
\newtheorem{choicethm}{Question}[exthm]
\newcommand\WhichThm{}
\newcommand\choicerange{0 }%

\makeatletter
\newcommand\DoNotIgnoreChoice[1]{\@bsphack\xdef\choicerange{\number\numexpr#1-1\relax\space}\@esphack}
\newcommand\DoIgnoreChoice[1]{\@bsphack\@esphack}
\newcommand\choice{}%
\global\let\choice=\DoNotIgnoreChoice
\global\let\WhichThm=\@firstoftwo
\newcommand\nestingerror{}%
\newcommand\nestingerrormessage{%
    \GenericError{\space \space \space \@spaces \@spaces \@spaces }%
                 {Error:\space nested \@currenvir-environments}%
                 {Don't nest \@currenvir-environments.}%
                 {Nesting \@currenvir-environments is not a good idea.}%
}%
\newenvironment{ex}{%
  \nestingerror
  \let\nestingerror=\nestingerrormessage
  \WhichThm
  {%
    \global\let\choice=\DoIgnoreChoice
    \begin{exthm}%
  }%
  {\begin{choicethm}}%
}{%
  \WhichThm
  {%
     \end{exthm}%
     \global\let\WhichThm=\@secondoftwo
  }%
  {\end{choicethm}}%
  \ifnum\value{choicethm}<\choicerange
  \else
     \global\let\WhichThm=\@firstoftwo
     \global\let\choice=\DoNotIgnoreChoice
     \choice{1}%
  \fi
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\choice{2}
\begin{ex}
an example
\end{ex}
\begin{ex}
A question developed from the example above
\end{ex}
\choice{3}
\begin{ex}
another example
\end{ex}
\begin{ex}
A question develops from this second example
\end{ex}
\begin{ex}
A question develops from this second example 
\end{ex}
\choice{5}
\begin{ex}
another example
\end{ex}
\begin{ex}
A question develops from this third example
\end{ex}
\begin{ex}
A question develops from this third example
\end{ex}
\begin{ex}
A question develops from this third example
\end{ex}
\begin{ex}
A question develops from this third example
\end{ex}

\end{document}
```

[image]

`\choice`-commands between things that are treated as questions belonging to a previously initiated  example are ignored.

E.g., with

```
\choice{2}
\begin{ex}
an example
\end{ex}
\choice{6}
\begin{ex}
A question developed from the example above
\end{ex}
```

the command `\choice{6}` will be ignored as at the time of encountering that command not all `ex`-environments belonging to the example initiated by `\choice{2}` were processed yet.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This is exactly what I need. Wish you good health and happiness.

Comment: Thanks to everyone's feedback for this question.